# How to change `ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging` package style in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, pagination, paging

I am working on a `Asp.net core 2.2` project and use `ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging` package for paging.
Every thing is ok but i want to change paging style in my view.

Here is code to use `Pager` view component

```
    <nav>
        @await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { PagingList = this.Model })
    </nav>
```

And here is paging pic :

[image]

I want to write `First` And `Last` instead of `1` And `15` in above pic and want to change some css styles.

Comment: You can set style such as other element

Comment: @saeed But how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create your own Pager view if you want to. You store it in the folder `Views\Shared\Components\Pager` :

[image]

You can for instance call the `AddPaging` method which you can use to set the `PagingOptions`. This allows you to specify which View is used for the Pager ViewComponent , in `ConfigureServices`function :

```
// Register ViewComponent using an EmbeddedFileProvider & setting some options
services.AddPaging(options => {
    options.ViewName = "Bootstrap5";
    options.HtmlIndicatorDown = " <span>&darr;</span>";
    options.HtmlIndicatorUp = " <span>&uarr;</span>";
});
```

Modify the `Bootstrap5.cshtml` to fit your requirement :

```
@model  ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.IPagingList

@* Fake Boostrap 5 based pager *@

@{
    var start = this.Model.StartPageIndex;
    var stop = this.Model.StopPageIndex;
}

@if (this.Model.PageCount > 1) {
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-end">

        @if (start > 1) {
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(1))" aria-label="First" class="page-link">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

        @if (this.Model.PageIndex > 1) {
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(this.Model.PageIndex - 1))" aria-label="Previous" class="page-link">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

        @for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
            <li class="page-item @((Model.PageIndex == i) ? "active" : null)">
            @if (i == 1)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("First", Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(i), new { @class = "page-link" })
                }
                else{
                    @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(i), new { @class = "page-link" })
                }

            </li>
        }

        @if (this.Model.PageIndex < this.Model.PageCount) {
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(this.Model.PageIndex + 1))" aria-label="Next" class="page-link">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

        @if (stop < this.Model.PageCount) {
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(this.Model.PageCount))" aria-label="Last" class="page-link">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

    </ul>
}
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
services.AddPaging(options => {
    options.ViewName = "Bootstrap4";
    options.HtmlIndicatorDown = " <span>&darr;</span>";
    options.HtmlIndicatorUp = " <span>&uarr;</span>";
});
```